# Bash script check file for specific data, remove them, replace them with new data

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

We have number of Linux Ubuntu 20-22, CentOS 7/RedHat 8 servers all on wrong timezone.
I am tasked to synchronize the time on all of them.

I tried many options, sed, awk, grep. "awk" has been the most confusing, and not friendly.
"sed" allowed me to replace the existing entries, but i am unable to implement it in a for loop that will check if the entries are correct then exit, if not then replace them all.

I have been struggling with this for the past 2 weeks now because I am fairly new to Bash programming.

So, I am trying to create a generic script for all of them to replace the entries in chrony.conf

For example on Ubuntu the `chrony.conf` has the following entries:

```
# pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
# pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
```

On CentOS 7 `chrony.conf` has the following entries

```
# server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
# server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

If the script encounters the entries above, then it should replace with the entries below:

```
pool time.nrc.ca iburst 
pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst
```

Any help / guidance is appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, if the entries in `chrony.conf` is as it is shown, i.e. if it starts with `#` then you don't need to delete them. Just append your string `pool time.nrc.ca iburst ` and `pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst` in `chrony.conf` using `echo "pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf` and `echo "pool time.nrc.ca iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf`

Comment: If files may have multiple lines to replace with single one, split the task into two: 1) delete unneeded lines (or comment them out); 2) append required line. But NTP servers work with UTC, how is this related to timezones? Probably you need to configure correct timezone, not NTP servers.

Comment: Why do you need to test first, whether all entries  are correct? Just go ahead with your `sed` or `awk` approach, and assume that they are not correct. Your tool would then simply don't find a line to replace, and in effect an already correct file stays unchanged afterwards. Perhaps the only drawback will be, that the time stamp of the file has been changed; but do you see this as a problem?

Comment: Regarding `"awk" has been the most confusing, and not friendly` - awk is mostly just a tiny subset of `C` inside an implicit `while read line` loop, it's only confusing and unfriendly if you don't glance at a man page to understand that first and try to use it as if it were `C` or similar. It's vastly clearer and simpler than `sed` for anything more than `s/old/new/`.

Comment: I tried the man page for awk, it's not as straight forward, possibly it's easier for you as you may have been scripting for a while now, for beginners, it's still confusing. I got most of my answers reading the forums.

Comment: @user1934428 , The reason I have to verify if the existing data is correct because script I prepared is deployed in Azure policy, so Azure deploys the script on all Linux VMs, and that's where the script will check if the time is correct, then exit, if not, then replace it with new time.

Comment: For explicit veryification, I would still first to do the replacement to an some temporary output file. After this, I would compare this output file to the original file. If there are no differences, nothing was to be replaced and the temp file can simply be deleted. If there are differences, move the temp file over the original file.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, that's what exactly my script now does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear in a few areas, e.g. what to do if only one of the target lines is present, what to do if the target text appears mid-line, what to do if neither line is present, what to do if the target text and replacement text are both already present, where to place the replacement text, etc., so here's one guess at what you might want, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    {
        despaced = $0
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",despaced)
    }
    ( despaced == "# pool ntp.ubuntu.com iburst maxsources 4" ) ||
    ( despaced == "# pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1" ) {
        $0 = "pool time.nrc.ca iburst"
    }
    ( despaced == "# server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst" ) ||
    ( despaced == "# server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst" ) {
        $0 = "pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst"
    }
    { print }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ head ubuntu_chrony.conf cent_chrony.conf
==> ubuntu_chrony.conf <==
# pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
# pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1

==> cent_chrony.conf <==
# server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
# server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

```
$ ./tst.sh ubuntu_chrony.conf
pool time.nrc.ca iburst
pool time.nrc.ca iburst
```

```
$ ./tst.sh cent_chrony.conf
pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst
pool time.chu.nrc.ca iburst
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @Ed Morton, I solved it with a different approach, using combination of awk, sed, and for loop. if the Target lines are present i need to verify them if they are correct before deleting or replacing them. The script i prepared is deployed in Azure policy, so Azure deploys the script, and that's where the script will check if the time is correct, then exit, if not, then replace it with new time zone.